# My static files are not loading due to permission denied?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-151:~$ sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log         
2023/12/28 05:14:20 [error] 17570#17570: *14 open() "/home/ubuntu/Donor/static/assets/plugins/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.191.136.55, server: 44.222.2.190, request: "GET /static/assets/plugins/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css HTTP/1.1", host: "44.222.2.190", referrer: "http://44.222.2.190/" 
2023/12/28 05:14:21 [error] 17570#17570: *12 open() "/home/ubuntu/Donor/static/assets/plugins/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.191.130.7, server: 44.222.2.190, request: "GET /static/assets/plugins/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "44.222.2.190", referrer: "http://44.222.2.190/" 
2023/12/28 05:14:21 [error] 17570#17570: *13 open() "/home/ubuntu/Donor/static/assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 182.191.130.7, server: 44.222.2.190, request: "GET /static/assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "44.222.2.190", referrer: "http://44.222.2.190/"
```

This is the error how could I solve this

I am using Nginx and Gunicorn for deploying my django app.

Comment: Check what the user is in your main nginx.conf file  if it says www-data, you should change it to the user you are using, and also make sure that the username group can enter through all of your directory chmod g+x /username && chmod g+x /username/test && chmod g+x /username/test/staticc